# Wordpress can't reach a page after added SSL certificate to my VPS

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, ubuntu

Hi I tried to add WordPress web online but  i have some issues with SSL (LetsEncrypt). After i install it exactly like in this link bellow:

https://websiteforstudents.com/switch-wordpress-from-http-to-https-on-ubuntu-with-lets-encrypt-and-apache2/

The page is just loading for a while and then it just show ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

I think everything should be ok but don't know why it no work.

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

wordpress-ls-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAdmin admin@example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress/
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias www.ecample.com

     <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined



Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

apache2 wordpress.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress/
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias www.example.com

     <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Without SSL it works fine. And also I changed in database wordpress links to https://

Comment: Are you exposing the webserver on the right port? HTTPS typically connects over 443, whereas HTTP (no S) uses 80. I don't really know how to read `.htaccess` files, but that `RewriteCond ${SERVER_PORT} 80` seems suspicious, and `<VirtualHost *:80>` seems odd, too.

Comment: No it wasn't that problem but thx to you a realize that i have probably blocked port. THX It works.

Comment: You should post that answer as an answer, not in the question.

Comment: Using port number `80` for your virtual host, makes it impossible to find your page when trying to get it through port `443` (port used by `https`) Look there...

Comment: look that you write `www.ecample.com` instead of `www.example.com`.  You have a lot to correct to get it working.

Comment: Just mistake after rewrite my code here on stackowerflow i didn't want to show you my real url. Now my site is on and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to unblock the port.

```
sudo ufw allow https
```

Comment: worse!!! If you have also a firewall, then you'll have more problems than only the port number. :)

Comment: then you are lucky! :)